# No JsonResponse Obtained even when single data is null

Tags: php, android, mysql

```
  {"futsal_id":"59",
    "description":[{
    "futsal_id":"59",
    "futsal_desc":"This is great futsal"}],

    "features":[{"futsal_id":"59","futsal_feat":"free 4 bottles of water"}],
    "dimension":null,
    "no_of_futsal":null,
    "opening_hrs":null,
    "price_weekdays_price1":[{
            "futsal_id":"59",
            "price_id":"1",
            "start_time":"6am",
            "end_time":"10am",
            "price":"1000"}],
    "price_weekdays_price2":[{
            "futsal_id":"59",
            "price_id":"2",
            "start_time":"10am",
            "end_time":"3pm",
            "price":"1200"}],
    "price_weekdays_price3":[{
            "futsal_id":"59",
            "price_id":"3",
            "start_time":"3pm",
            "end_time":"9pm",
            "price":"1300"}],
    "price_weekend_price1":null,
            "price_weekend_price2":null,
            "price_weekend_price3":null,
    "images":[],
    "image_count":0,
    "news":null}
```

This is My JsonResponse from PHP.
I cannot get any of this response in android studio with these response because of present null data in these response.
If no null data are present, response.getString() has all these data but response.getString has no response because of null data.
What might be the problem?

```
    class ShowResult extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        pd.cancel();
        txt.setText(result[0]);
      }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Log.d("sssssssssssssss", "sadf");

            URL url = new URL("http://futsalgroove.s4generation.com/app/android_c/show_details/");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            String urlParameters = "id=" + bundle.getString("id");
            //sending the parameter using DataOutputStream
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            //Reading the data or response from the PHP file
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

            Log.d("sssssssssssssss", "iii" + in);
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
                Log.d("Detail Outputss", inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            //Using the JasonObject from php
            Log.d("Detail Outputsss", "" + response.toString());

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());

            JSONArray description = json.getJSONArray("description");
            JSONObject descObj = description.getJSONObject(0);

            result[0] =  descObj.getString("futsal_desc");
            Log.d("DetailOut","" + result[0]);
     }

       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add some more details and format the json code so that it is more readable

Comment: Leave android out of. Load the url in your browser and check the json. Having a json parser extension helps. If not you can use the developer console.

Comment: Log.d("Detail Outputsss", "" + response.toString()); what it prints...??

Comment: Nothings shows in response .toString() 
If theres no null value in my response , then response.toString() has all value.. response.toString() is getting no values because of the null data

Comment: @Nabin Can you print and check what does urlConnection.getResponseCode() gives?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());
JSONArray description = json.getJSONArray("description");
JSONObject descObj = description.getJSONObject(0);
result[0] =  descObj.getString("futsal_desc");
Log.d("DetailOut","" + result[0]);
```

with

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(response.toString());
JArray description = (JArray)json["description"];
JObject descObj = (JObject)description[0];
result[0] = descObj["futsal_desc"].ToString();
Log.d("DetailOut","" + result[0]);
```

may be this will work. for JObject use Newtonsoft.Json.Linq on top

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```